# Xtra Report Multi Column Layout AcrossthenDown does support keeping whole group together in in one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I have designed a report in xtrareports I am facing issues with Xtra Report Multi Column Layout AcrossthenDown does not support keeping the whole group together in the column I am illustrating as an Image also. I have Created a Group also but it is not keeping that group in one column. so finding it very difficult also it is not repeating group headers in 2nd column also.

Please help me what I am missing also there is a requirement to add more content at the last of the report in a column. but in a different band and the band must be positioned last.